# Какие существуют руководства по написанию кода на C#?

Tags: c#, чистый-код

Например в python есть PEP 8. Есть ли нечто похожее по содержанию, но для C#?

Comment: Есть как минимум Роберт Мартин - Чистый Код

Comment: и Принципы, паттерны и методики гибкой разработки на языке C#, Роберт С. Мартин, Мика Мартин

Comment: а так, прям у микрософт и есть всё:  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) содержат множество рекомендаций. Также советую одноименную [книгу](https://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613) от авторов дотнета.